# XSLT 2.0: Adding a new element in its valid place in a sequence of elements as specified by an xsd:sequence

Tags: sequence, xslt-2.0

Consider the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.zoo.org/animals" targetNamespace="http://www.zoo.org/animals" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0.0">

    <xsd:complexType name="Animals_Type">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="Cat" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element ref="Dog" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element ref="Mouse" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element ref="Lion" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element ref="Tiger" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element ref="Bear" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element ref="Penguin" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element ref="Monkey" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="Animals" type="Animals_Type"/>
    <xsd:element name="Cat" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Dog" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Mouse" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Lion" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Tiger" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Bear" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Penguin" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Monkey" type="xsd:string"/>

</xsd:schema>
```

With the following input xml:

```
<Animals xmlns="http://www.zoo.org/animals">
    <Cat>Pixel</Cat>
    <Dog>Ada</Dog>
    <Mouse>Minnie</Mouse>
    <Lion>Donnie</Lion>
    <Tiger>Phil</Tiger>
    <Bear>Susie</Bear>
    <Penguin>Bob</Penguin>
    <Monkey>Lennie</Monkey>
</Animals>
```

Where the desired output xml is to add a Bear named Billy:

```
<Animals xmlns="http://www.zoo.org/animals">
    <Cat>Pixel</Cat>
    <Dog>Ada</Dog>
    <Mouse>Minnie</Mouse>
    <Lion>Donnie</Lion>
    <Tiger>Phil</Tiger>
    <Bear>Susie</Bear>
    <Bear>Billy</Bear>
    <Penguin>Bob</Penguin>
    <Monkey>Lennie</Monkey>
</Animals>
```

The following xslt will add Billy the Bear to the xml, however it will add Billy at the end after all other elements are copied and thus will create a schema invalid xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.zoo.org/animals">

    <!-- element template that copies over elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Animals">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            <xsl:element name="Bear" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">Billy</xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Creates schema invalid xml due to sequence out of order:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Animals xmlns="http://www.zoo.org/animals">
    <Cat>Pixel</Cat>
    <Dog>Ada</Dog>
    <Mouse>Minnie</Mouse>
    <Lion>Donnie</Lion>
    <Tiger>Phil</Tiger>
    <Bear>Susie</Bear>
    <Penguin>Bob</Penguin>
    <Monkey>Lennie</Monkey>
    <Bear>Billy</Bear>
</Animals>
```

A better xslt that will add Billy the Bear in the correct location is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.zoo.org/animals">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- element template that copies over elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Animals">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::Penguin)][not(self::Monkey)]" />
            <xsl:element name="Bear" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">Billy</xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::Cat)][not(self::Dog)][not(self::Mouse)][not(self::Lion)][not(self::Tiger)][not(self::Bear)]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Creates correct xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Animals xmlns="http://www.zoo.org/animals">
    <Cat>Pixel</Cat>
    <Dog>Ada</Dog>
    <Mouse>Minnie</Mouse>
    <Lion>Donnie</Lion>
    <Tiger>Phil</Tiger>
    <Bear>Susie</Bear>
    <Bear>Billy</Bear>
    <Penguin>Bob</Penguin>
    <Monkey>Lennie</Monkey>
</Animals>
```

The concern I have with this xslt is that it is directly coupled to the current schema. For instance if the schema is later updated with a simple element addition to the sequence, this xslt will break.

What is the most flexible way to add an element to the middle of a sequence? Is there a transform that can be written such that new elements being added to the sequence in the future will not break the transform?

Comment: Is there always a sequence? With the schema you have the `Animals` element could be empty. If you know there is always at least one `Bear` in the XML input then I would match on `Bear[last()]` and inside use `<xsl:next-match/>` for the copy and a literal result element or `xsl:element` to insert the new `Bear`

Comment: I definitely like that idea! That's a really good solution for elements where the minOccurs is set to 1 (required). Unfortunately the element I'm working with (bear in this question for illustration purposes) has a minOccurs of 0 (optional). I read yesterday about schema aware xslt processors, but thus far the reading seems to suggest it's mainly around making sure input and output is schema valid. It would be awesome to have the ability to be so schema aware of the output that we could add children and it would take care of the sequence but thus far no reading points to those capabilities =/

Comment: I should further clarify. For the sake of discussion let's assume Animals will always be present, however all of the child elements of it are optional. That best mimics my real world scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**I believe you want something like this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:zoo="http://www.zoo.org/animals">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pAddElementName" select="'Bear'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pAddValue" select="'Billy'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSchema" select="document('animals.xsd')"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vElementNameSpecified" select=
    "$vSchema/*/xs:complexType[@name='Animals_Type']
                   /xs:sequence/xs:element[@ref=$pAddElementName]"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vPreceding" select=
    "$vSchema/*/xs:complexType[@name='Animals_Type']
                   /xs:sequence
                     /xs:element[following-sibling::xs:element
                                         [@ref=$pAddElementName]]/@ref/string()"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vFollowing" select=
    "$vSchema/*/xs:complexType[@name='Animals_Type']
                   /xs:sequence
                       /xs:element[preceding-sibling::xs:element
                                        [@ref=$pAddElementName]]/@ref/string()"/>


  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*[$vElementNameSpecified]/zoo:*[name()=$vPreceding][last()]">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$pAddElementName}" namespace="http://www.zoo.org/animals">
      <xsl:sequence select="$pAddValue"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*[$vElementNameSpecified][not(zoo:*[name()=$vPreceding])]
                                                     /zoo:*[name()=$vFollowing][1]">
    <xsl:element name="{$pAddElementName}" namespace="http://www.zoo.org/animals">
      <xsl:sequence select="$pAddValue"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*[$vElementNameSpecified]
                           [not(zoo:*[name()=$vPreceding]) 
                          and not(zoo:*[name()=$vFollowing])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$pAddElementName}" namespace="http://www.zoo.org/animals">
          <xsl:sequence select="$pAddValue"/>
        </xsl:element>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The XML Schema is accessed using the `document()` function.
2. All different names of elements that can precede the element to be added, are dynamically identified.
3. All different names of elements that can follow the element to be added, are dynamically identified.
4. There are three cases: a) preceding elements exist; b) preceding elements don't exist, but following elements exist; c) neither preceding elements nor following elements exist. The transformation contains a template for each of these cases, that adds the wanted new element in its correct place.